# Send Bitcoin Pool Information to another system for solving

Tags: bitcoin

I have a rig that I'd like to use for Bitcoin Mining. The rig has no access to the internet, but has the capability to SSH in to the machine. Unfortunetly there's no way I can fix this, so I'm looking for a work around.

If I'm part of a pool, is it possible to send the information to this other system through SSH for solving, then send it back to my main machine to send back to the pool?

Comment: Which pool is it?  Does it have a single address the rig needs to interact with, or is it a p2p pool?

Comment: Single Address. BTC Guild for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a reverse tunnel.  For example, if you were targetting the port/address `198.100.146.114:3333` for btcguild.

From the machine that **can** get to btcguild, you do this:

```
ssh -R3333:198.100.146.114:3333 user@rig
```

This logs into your rig, and on it opens port 3333 on 127.0.0.1.  Anything that the rig directs down 127.0.0.1:3333 gets tunnelled to the machine you are sshing from, and is then forwarded on to `198.100.146.114:3333`

You would then configure your mining rig to talk to 127.0.0.1:3333 and it will be directly talking to the btcguild server.

You would need to ensure the ssh server is configured to allow the session to maintain indefinitely.  And all ssh clients I have seen will do a reverse tunnel, so you just need to find out how for the client you are using.